# How to efficiently do a grid search for parameter combinations in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, combinatorics

## Problem

For a computation engineering model, I want to do a grid search for all feasible parameter combinations. Each parameter has a certain possibility range, e.g. (0 … 100) and the parameter combination must fulfil the condition `a+b+c=100`. An example:

```
ranges = {
    'a': (95, 99), 
    'b': (1, 4), 
    'c': (1, 2)}
increment = 1.0
target = 100.0
```

So the combinations *that fulfil the condition* `a+b+c=100` are:

```
[(95, 4, 1), (95, 3, 2), (96, 2, 2), (96, 3, 1), (97, 1, 2), (97, 2, 1), (98, 1, 1)]
```

This algorithm should run with any number of parameters, range lengths, and increments.

## My solutions (so far)

The solutions I have come up with are all brute-forcing the problem. That means calculating *all* combinations and then discarding the ones that do not fulfil the given condition:

```
def solution1(ranges, increment, target):
    combinations = []
    for parameter in ranges:
        combinations.append(list(np.arange(ranges[parameter][0], ranges[parameter][1], increment)))
        # np.arange() is exclusive of the upper bound, let's fix that
        if combinations[-1][-1] != ranges[parameter][1]:
            combinations[-1].append(ranges[parameter][1])
    combinations = list(itertools.product(*combinations))
    df = pd.DataFrame(combinations, columns=ranges.keys())
    # using np.isclose() so that the algorithm works for floats
    return df[np.isclose(df.sum(axis=1), target)]
```

Since I ran into RAM problems with `solution1()`, I used `itertools.product` as an iterator.

```
def solution2(ranges, increment, target):
    combinations = []
    for parameter in ranges:
        combinations.append(list(np.arange(ranges[parameter][0], ranges[parameter][1], increment)))
        # np.arange() is exclusive of the upper bound, let's fix that
        if combinations[-1][-1] != ranges[parameter][1]:
            combinations[-1].append(ranges[parameter][1])
    result = []
    for combination in itertools.product(*combinations):
        # using np.isclose() so that the algorithm works for floats
        if np.isclose(sum(combination), target):
            result.append(combination)
    df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=ranges.keys())
    return df
```

However, this quickly takes a few days to compute. Hence, both solutions are not viable for large number of parameters and ranges. For instance, one set that I am trying to solve is (already unpacked `combinations` variable):

```
[[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0, 21.0, 22.0, 23.0], [22.0, 23.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0, 28.0, 29.0, 30.0, 31.0, 32.0, 33.0, 34.0, 35.0, 36.0, 37.0, 38.0, 39.0, 40.0, 41.0, 42.0, 43.0, 44.0, 45.0, 46.0, 47.0, 48.0, 49.0, 50.0, 51.0, 52.0, 53.0, 54.0, 55.0, 56.0, 57.0, 58.0, 59.0, 60.0, 61.0, 62.0, 63.0, 64.0, 65.0, 66.0, 67.0, 68.0, 69.0, 70.0, 71.0, 72.0, 73.0, 74.0, 75.0, 76.0, 77.0, 78.0, 79.0, 80.0, 81.0, 82.0, 83.0, 84.0, 85.0, 86.0, 87.0, 88.0], [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0, 21.0, 22.0, 23.0], [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0], [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0], [0.0, 1.0, 2.0], [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0], [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0], [0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0, 21.0, 22.0, 23.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0, 28.0, 29.0, 30.0, 31.0, 32.0], [0.0]]
```

This results in memory use of >40 GB for `solution1()` and calculation time >400 hours for `solution2()`.

## Question

Do you see a solution that is either faster or more intelligent, i.e. not trying to brute-force the problem?

P.S.: *I am not 100% sure if this question would be a better fit on one of the other Stackexchange sites. Please suggest in the comments if you think it should be moved and I will delete it here.*

Comment: You might need a dynamic programming approach. You should not consider further choices for subsets that are already invalid.

Comment: I tried solution1, and it took 19 milliseconds and no memory warnings were generated.  Did you run it on different data, and if so, what?

Comment: A small trick I can think of is to first sort your parameters based on the mid of their ranges. Build up your possible combination starting from the parameter with the largest mid range. In this way, say you looked at `a=95`, you do not have to iterate any `b` if b's range is (30, 60)

Comment: @Acccumulation I edited the question with an example. Hope this helps...

Comment: You can skip the rest of the loop iteration if `a + b > 100` (assuming c > 0) or if `a + b < 100 + max(c)`. You can also replace the last iteration with `(100 - a - b) in c`, and make `c` a set to reduce from n^3 to n^2 runtime

Comment: Also, do you need to search every value of a,b,c? If the evaluation function is continuous, you could use gradient descent/ simulated annealing to find the min/ max. Finally, do you need to store every value in the dataframe or could you use a generator instead?

Comment: @user3080953 sounds like good questions / suggestions. However, I don’t know very much about these things, I‘m afraid. An example / answer would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive solution:

```
a = [95, 100]
b = [1, 4]
c = [1, 2]

Params = (a, b, c)

def GetValidParamValues(Params, constriantSum, prevVals):
    validParamValues = []
    if (len(Params) == 1):
        if (constriantSum >= Params[0][0] and constriantSum <= Params[0][1]):
            validParamValues.append(constriantSum)
        for v in validParamValues:
            print(prevVals + v)
        return
    sumOfLowParams = sum([Params[x][0] for x in range(1, len(Params))])
    sumOfHighParams = sum([Params[x][1] for x in range(1, len(Params))])
    lowEnd = max(Params[0][0], constriantSum - sumOfHighParams)
    highEnd = min(Params[0][1], constriantSum - sumOfLowParams) + 1
    if (len(Params) == 2):
        for av in range(lowEnd, highEnd):
            bv  = constriantSum - av
            if (bv <= Params[1][1]):
                validParamValues.append([av, bv])
        for v in validParamValues:
            print(prevVals + v)
        return
    for av in range(lowEnd, highEnd):
        nexPrevVals = prevVals + [av]
        subSeParams = Params[1:]
        GetValidParamValues(subSeParams, constriantSum - av, nexPrevVals)


GetValidParamValues(Params, 100)
```

The idea is that if there were 2 parameters, `a` and `b`, we could list all the valid pairs by passing through the values of `a`, and taking `(ai, S - ai)` and just checking if `S-ai` is a valid value for `b`.

This is improved on since we can calculate ahead of time which values of `ai` will make `S-ai` a valid value for `b`, so we never check values that don't work.

When the number of params is more than 2, we can again look at every valid value of `ai`, and we know the sum of the other numbers must be `S - ai`. So the only thing we need is every possible way for the other numbers to add to `S - ai`, which is the same problem with one fewer parameter. So by using recursion we can get it go all the way down to size 2 and solve it.

Comment: Thank you!! I could make it work using the example data from my question by a. converting the numbers to floats and b. removing sub-lists with only one element. It has been running now for 13+ minutes and memory footprint is 16GB and growing. I am not sure how to use a progressbar in a recursive function so I cannot tell how far it is in. However, I have the feeling like this solution may not help me very much, I am afraid.

Comment: Can you give the example you're running? There are probably some optimizations to be made, for example doing a bounds check in the case of length greater than 3 to avoid checking values of av that won't work based on the sum of the the other bounds

Comment: I edited my solution, it should be faster and use less memory now

Comment: I am using the example also given in the question: `Params = [[0.0, 23.0], [22.0, 88.0], [0.0, 23.0], [0.0, 12.0], [0.0, 9.0], [0.0, 2.0], [0.0, 10.0], [0.0, 8.0], [0.0, 32.0], [0.0]]` but removed to lists with `[0]`

Comment: I started running your example (with [0] removed) on my computer with some debug timing code, and it looks like it will take about 62 minutes to finish (it took 154.8 seconds find all the values with the first parameter = 0, still has to do [1,23])

Comment: I edited again to reduce the memory requirements. I don't keep the list of answers in RAM. You can replace the print with a write to file. It's a massive amount of data.

Comment: With those changes, I'm estimating 21 minutes of runtime and 24 GB of results